# Using pivot and getting Error missing Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00936

i am trying to use pivot in my query but getting error :

> **ORA-00936** : *missing expression*

below is my query :

```
select *
  from t_product
  PIVOT(
  sum(jira_value)
   FOR jira
   in (['C_MIN'],['C_MAX'])
   )
```

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of square brackets and use as :

```
select *
  from t_product
  PIVOT(
  sum(jira_value) as sum_jira
   FOR (jira)
   in ('C_MIN' as c_min ,'C_MAX' as c_max )
   );
```